# Lower bound of $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)dx$ is undefined but online calculators ignore it?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to manually evaluate$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)dx$.

I used integration by parts to find the indefinite integral first like this:

Let $u=2\ln(x)\Rightarrow u'=\frac{2}{x}$ and $v'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Rightarrow v=2x^{\frac{1}{2}}=2\sqrt{x}$:

$\Rightarrow\int\left(\frac{2\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)dx=uv-\int\left(u'\cdot v\right)dx=2\ln(x)\cdot 2\sqrt{x}-\int\left(\frac{2}{x}\cdot2\sqrt{x}\right)dx$

$\hspace{31mm}=4\sqrt{x}\ln(x)-\int\left(4x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)dx=4\sqrt{x}\ln(x)-8\sqrt{x}+C$

At this point, I realized that the lower bound $0$ will make $\ln(x)$ undefined. Online calculators show that the definite integral is $-8$, which is found by plugging in the upper bound only.

How do they ignore the lower bound?

Comment: In brief, the key is that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\sqrt{x}\ln(x) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

You may just substitute $x=z^2$, then $z=e^{-u}$, and end up with
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = 8\int_{0}^{1}\ln(z)\,dz=-8\int_{0}^{+\infty}u e^{-u}\,du=-8\,\Gamma(2)=-8. $$

Comment: Hi Jack ! Long time no see !

Answer (score 1):

As @Ben Grossmann pointed out it results that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\sqrt x\ln x=0\,.$

Now, we will prove it.

$\ln t<t\;\;$ for any $\,t>0\,.\quad\color{blue}{(1)} $
In particular, for $\,t=\dfrac1{\sqrt[4]x}\,,\,$ from $\,(1)\,,\,$ we get that
$-\dfrac14\ln x=\ln\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt[4]x}\right)<\dfrac1{\sqrt[4]x}\;\;$ for any $\,x>0\,.$

Consequently, for any $\,x\in(0,1)\,,\,$ it results that

$0<-\sqrt x\ln x=4\sqrt x\left(-\dfrac14\ln x\right)<4\sqrt x\dfrac1{\sqrt[4]x}=4\sqrt[4]x\;.$

Since
$0<-\sqrt x\ln x<4\sqrt[4]x\;\;\;\forall x\in(0,1)\;$ and $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}4\sqrt[4]x=0\;,$
by applying Squeeze Theorem, it follows that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\sqrt x\ln x=0\,.$